# How to print from picturebox

Tags: vb.net

I am having trouble trying to print a generated barcode image from the picturebox. When I click on the print button I get to print to window, but when printed only a white piece of paper comes out.

The code is below

```
Imports System.Drawing.Printing

Public Class Barcode_Generator

    'CENTER FORM TO SCREEN
    Dim WithEvents printdoc As New Printing.PrintDocument()
    Dim pd_printdialog As New PrintDialog

    Private Property PrintDialog1 As PrintDialog

    Private Sub Barcode128_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.CenterToScreen()
    End Sub

    'GENERATE BARCODE STRING
    Private Function Code128B(foo As String) As String
        Dim C(107) As String
        Dim B(107) As String
        Dim S(107) As String
        Dim w(255) As String
        Dim l As Integer = 0
        Dim t As String = ""
        Dim n, i As Integer
        Dim check As Long = 0
        Code128B = ""

        B(0) = " " : C(0) = "00" : S(0) = "bb w bb ww bb ww"
        B(1) = "!" : C(1) = "01" : S(1) = "bb ww bb w bb ww"
        B(2) = Chr(34) : C(2) = "02" : S(2) = "bb ww bb ww bb w"
        B(3) = "#" : C(3) = "03" : S(3) = "b ww b ww bb www"
        B(4) = "$" : C(4) = "04" : S(4) = "b ww b www bb ww"
        B(5) = "%" : C(5) = "05" : S(5) = "b www b ww bb ww"
        B(6) = "&" : C(6) = "06" : S(6) = "b ww bb ww b www"
        B(7) = "'" : C(7) = "07" : S(7) = "b ww bb www b ww"
        B(8) = "(" : C(8) = "08" : S(8) = "b www bb ww b ww"
        B(9) = ")" : C(9) = "09" : S(9) = "bb ww b ww b www"
        B(10) = "*" : C(10) = "10" : S(10) = "bb ww b www b ww"
        B(11) = "+" : C(11) = "11" : S(11) = "bb www b ww b ww"
        B(12) = "," : C(12) = "12" : S(12) = "b w bb ww bbb ww"
        B(13) = "-" : C(13) = "13" : S(13) = "b ww bb w bbb ww"
        B(14) = "." : C(14) = "14" : S(14) = "b ww bb ww bbb w"
        B(15) = "/" : C(15) = "15" : S(15) = "b w bbb ww bb ww"
        B(16) = "0" : C(16) = "16" : S(16) = "b ww bbb w bb ww"
        B(17) = "1" : C(17) = "17" : S(17) = "b ww bbb ww bb w"
        B(18) = "2" : C(18) = "18" : S(18) = "bb ww bbb ww b w"
        B(19) = "3" : C(19) = "19" : S(19) = "bb ww b w bbb ww"
        B(20) = "4" : C(20) = "20" : S(20) = "bb ww b ww bbb w"
        B(21) = "5" : C(21) = "21" : S(21) = "bb w bbb ww b ww"
        B(22) = "6" : C(22) = "22" : S(22) = "bb ww bbb w b ww"
        B(23) = "7" : C(23) = "23" : S(23) = "bbb w bb w bbb w"
        B(24) = "8" : C(24) = "24" : S(24) = "bbb w b ww bb ww"
        B(25) = "9" : C(25) = "25" : S(25) = "bbb ww b w bb ww"
        B(26) = ":" : C(26) = "26" : S(26) = "bbb ww b ww bb w"
        B(27) = ";" : C(27) = "27" : S(27) = "bbb w bb ww b ww"
        B(28) = "<" : C(28) = "28" : S(28) = "bbb ww bb w b ww"
        B(29) = "=" : C(29) = "29" : S(29) = "bbb ww bb ww b w"
        B(30) = ">" : C(30) = "30" : S(30) = "bb w bb w bb www"
        B(31) = "?" : C(31) = "31" : S(31) = "bb w bb www bb w"
        B(32) = "@" : C(32) = "32" : S(32) = "bb www bb w bb w"
        B(33) = "A" : C(33) = "33" : S(33) = "b w b www bb www"
        B(34) = "B" : C(34) = "34" : S(34) = "b www b w bb www"
        B(35) = "C" : C(35) = "35" : S(35) = "b www b www bb w"
        B(36) = "D" : C(36) = "36" : S(36) = "b w bb www b www"
        B(37) = "E" : C(37) = "37" : S(37) = "b www bb w b www"
        B(38) = "F" : C(38) = "38" : S(38) = "b www bb www b w"
        B(39) = "G" : C(39) = "39" : S(39) = "bb w b www b www"
        B(40) = "H" : C(40) = "40" : S(40) = "bb www b w b www"
        B(41) = "I" : C(41) = "41" : S(41) = "bb www b www b w"
        B(42) = "J" : C(42) = "42" : S(42) = "b w bb w bbb www"
        B(43) = "K" : C(43) = "43" : S(43) = "b w bb www bbb w"
        B(44) = "L" : C(44) = "44" : S(44) = "b www bb w bbb w"
        B(45) = "M" : C(45) = "45" : S(45) = "b w bbb w bb www"
        B(46) = "N" : C(46) = "46" : S(46) = "b w bbb www bb w"
        B(47) = "O" : C(47) = "47" : S(47) = "b www bbb w bb w"
        B(48) = "P" : C(48) = "48" : S(48) = "bbb w bbb w bb w"
        B(49) = "Q" : C(49) = "49" : S(49) = "bb w b www bbb w"
        B(50) = "R" : C(50) = "50" : S(50) = "bb www b w bbb w"
        B(51) = "S" : C(51) = "51" : S(51) = "bb w bbb w b www"
        B(52) = "T" : C(52) = "52" : S(52) = "bb w bbb www b w"
        B(53) = "U" : C(53) = "53" : S(53) = "bb w bbb w bbb w"
        B(54) = "V" : C(54) = "54" : S(54) = "bbb w b w bb www"
        B(55) = "W" : C(55) = "55" : S(55) = "bbb w b www bb w"
        B(56) = "X" : C(56) = "56" : S(56) = "bbb www b w bb w"
        B(57) = "Y" : C(57) = "57" : S(57) = "bbb w bb w b www"
        B(58) = "Z" : C(58) = "58" : S(58) = "bbb w bb www b w"
        B(59) = "[" : C(59) = "59" : S(59) = "bbb www bb w b w"
        B(60) = "\" : C(60) = "60" : S(60) = "bbb w bbbb w b w"
        B(61) = "]" : C(61) = "61" : S(61) = "bb ww b wwww b w"
        B(62) = "^" : C(62) = "62" : S(62) = "bbbb www b w b w"
        B(63) = "_" : C(63) = "63" : S(63) = "b w b ww bb wwww"
        B(64) = "`" : C(64) = "64" : S(64) = "b w b wwww bb ww"
        B(65) = "a" : C(65) = "65" : S(65) = "b ww b w bb wwww"
        B(66) = "b" : C(66) = "66" : S(66) = "b ww b wwww bb w"
        B(67) = "c" : C(67) = "67" : S(67) = "b wwww b w bb ww"
        B(68) = "d" : C(68) = "68" : S(68) = "b wwww b ww bb w"
        B(69) = "e" : C(69) = "69" : S(69) = "b w bb ww b wwww"
        B(70) = "f" : C(70) = "70" : S(70) = "b w bb wwww b ww"
        B(71) = "g" : C(71) = "71" : S(71) = "b ww bb w b wwww"
        B(72) = "h" : C(72) = "72" : S(72) = "b ww bb wwww b w"
        B(73) = "i" : C(73) = "73" : S(73) = "b wwww bb w b ww"
        B(74) = "j" : C(74) = "74" : S(74) = "b wwww bb ww b w"
        B(75) = "k" : C(75) = "75" : S(75) = "bb wwww b ww b w"
        B(76) = "l" : C(76) = "76" : S(76) = "bb ww b w b wwww"
        B(77) = "m" : C(77) = "77" : S(77) = "bbbb w bbb w b w"
        B(78) = "n" : C(78) = "78" : S(78) = "bb wwww b w b ww"
        B(79) = "o" : C(79) = "79" : S(79) = "b www bbbb w b w"
        B(80) = "p" : C(80) = "80" : S(80) = "b w b ww bbbb ww"
        B(81) = "q" : C(81) = "81" : S(81) = "b ww b w bbbb ww"
        B(82) = "r" : C(82) = "82" : S(82) = "b ww b ww bbbb w"
        B(83) = "s" : C(83) = "83" : S(83) = "b w bbbb ww b ww"
        B(84) = "t" : C(84) = "84" : S(84) = "b ww bbbb w b ww"
        B(85) = "u" : C(85) = "85" : S(85) = "b ww bbbb ww b w"
        B(86) = "v" : C(86) = "86" : S(86) = "bbbb w b ww b ww"
        B(87) = "w" : C(87) = "87" : S(87) = "bbbb ww b w b ww"
        B(88) = "x" : C(88) = "88" : S(88) = "bbbb ww b ww b w"
        B(89) = "y" : C(89) = "89" : S(89) = "bb w bb w bbbb w"
        B(90) = "z" : C(90) = "90" : S(90) = "bb w bbbb w bb w"
        B(91) = "{" : C(91) = "91" : S(91) = "bbbb w bb w bb w"
        B(92) = "|" : C(92) = "92" : S(92) = "b w b w bbbb www"
        B(93) = "}" : C(93) = "93" : S(93) = "b w b www bbbb w"
        B(94) = "~" : C(94) = "94" : S(94) = "b www b w bbbb w"

        'these code are not yet implemented
        B(95) = "del" : C(95) = "95" : S(95) = "b w bbbb w b www"
        B(96) = "func3" : C(96) = "96" : S(96) = "b w bbbb www b w"
        B(97) = "func2" : C(97) = "97" : S(97) = "bbbb w b w b www"
        B(98) = "Shift" : C(98) = "98" : S(98) = "bbbb w b www b w"
        B(99) = "Code C" : C(99) = "99" : S(99) = "b w bbb w bbbb w"
        B(100) = "func4" : C(100) = "Code B" : S(100) = "b w bbbb w bbb w"
        B(101) = "Code A" : C(101) = "Code A" : S(101) = "bbb w b w bbbb w"
        B(102) = "func1" : C(102) = "func1" : S(102) = "bbbb w b w bbb w"
        B(103) = "Start A" : C(103) = "Start A" : S(103) = "bb w b wwww b ww"

        'starting sign
        B(104) = "Start B" : C(104) = "Start B" : S(104) = "bb w b ww b wwww"

        'not implemented yet
        B(105) = "Start C" : C(105) = "Start C" : S(105) = "bb w b ww bbb ww"

        'very important...
        B(106) = "Stop" : C(106) = "Stop" : S(106) = "bb www bbb w b w bb"

        If foo = "" Then
            MsgBox("Error has occured!") ' no string ;-(
            Exit Function
        End If

        w(0) = "104" 'start
        check = 104 'start check value
        l = foo.Length
        For n = 1 To l
            For i = 0 To 94
                If foo.Substring(n - 1, 1) = B(i) Then
                    w(n) = C(i)
                    Exit For
                End If

            Next
            check = check + n * CInt(C(i))
            'MsgBox(CStr(n * CInt(C(i))))
        Next

        'MsgBox(CStr(check))

        l = l + 1
        w(l) = C(check Mod 103) 'checkzahl - check number

        l = l + 1
        w(l) = "106" 'stop

        Dim p As String = ""
        For n = 0 To l
            p = p + CStr(w(n)) & " "
        Next
        'MsgBox(p)

        For n = 0 To l
            Code128B = Code128B + S(CInt(w(n))) & " " 'ascii pendant basseln
        Next

        Code128B = Replace(Code128B, " ", "")
        Return Code128B

    End Function

    'GENERATE THE BARCODE IMAGE IN PICTURE BOX

    Private Function Code128Malen(c As String) As Image
        'convert string (b and w´s) to graphics
        Const w = 2
        Dim n, l As Integer
        l = c.Length

        Dim bm As New Bitmap(l * w, 80)
        Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bm)

        For n = 0 To l - 1
            If c.Substring(n, 1) = "b" Then g.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, n * w, 0, w, 80)
        Next
        Return bm
    End Function

    'PRINT OUT BARCODE

    Private Sub printdocument_printpage()
        PrintDocument1.Print()
    End Sub

    'CHANGE LABEL WHEN TEXBOX TEXT IS CHANGED

    Private Sub textinput_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles textinput.TextChanged
        Label2.Text = textinput.Text


    End Sub

    'SAVE BARCODE IMAGE
    Private Sub Button1_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim MyPicture As Image
        PictureBox1.Refresh()
        MyPicture = PictureBox1.Image

        Dim saveFileDialog1 As New SaveFileDialog()

        saveFileDialog1.Filter = "jpegs|*.jpg|gifs|*.gif|bitmaps|*.bmp"
        saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 1
        saveFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = True

        If saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then

            MyPicture.Save(saveFileDialog1.FileName, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp)
        End If

    End Sub

    'CLOSE MENU FORM

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    'GO BACK TO MAIN MENU SCREEN

    Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        Main_Menu.Show()
        Me.Hide()
    End Sub

    'SAVE IMAGE AS A BARCODE

    Private Sub Button5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
        Dim mypicture2 As Image
        PictureBox2.Refresh()
        mypicture2 = PictureBox2.Image
        Dim savefiledialog2 As New SaveFileDialog()
        savefiledialog2.Filter = "jpeg|*.jpeg|gif|*.gif|bmp|*.bmp"
        savefiledialog2.FilterIndex = 1
        savefiledialog2.RestoreDirectory = True

        If savefiledialog2.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            mypicture2.Save(savefiledialog2.FileName, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp)
        End If

    End Sub

    'PRINT OUT DOCUMENT BUTTON

    'Private Sub PrintDocument1_PrintPage(sender As Object, e As Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.PrintPage
    '    Dim g As Graphics = 

    '    g.DrawImage(PictureBox1.Image, New Point(100, 100))
    'End Sub


    'CHANGE LABEL WHEN TEXTBOX TEXT IS CHANGED

    Private Sub Textinput2_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Textinput2.TextChanged
        Label3.Text = Textinput2.Text
    End Sub

    'GENERATE BARCODE WHEN CLICKED 2

    Private Sub Button6_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click


        TextBoxstring2.Text = Code128B(Textinput2.Text)
        PictureBox2.Image = Code128Malen(TextBoxstring2.Text)


    End Sub

    'SECOND CODE MALEN 2

    Private Function Code128Malen2(c As String) As Image
        'convert string (b and w´s) to graphics
        Const w = 2
        Dim n, l As Integer
        l = c.Length

        Dim bmm As New Bitmap(l * w, 80)
        Dim gg As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmm)

        For n = 0 To l - 1
            If c.Substring(n, 1) = "b" Then gg.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, n * w, 0, w, 80)
        Next
        Return bmm
    End Function

    'GENERATE BARCODE STRING 2

    Private Function Code128B2(foo As String) As String
        Dim C(107) As String
        Dim B(107) As String
        Dim S(107) As String
        Dim w(255) As String
        Dim l As Integer = 0
        Dim t As String = ""
        Dim n, i As Integer
        Dim check As Long = 0
        Code128B2 = ""

        B(0) = " " : C(0) = "00" : S(0) = "bb w bb ww bb ww"
        B(1) = "!" : C(1) = "01" : S(1) = "bb ww bb w bb ww"
        B(2) = Chr(34) : C(2) = "02" : S(2) = "bb ww bb ww bb w"
        B(3) = "#" : C(3) = "03" : S(3) = "b ww b ww bb www"
        B(4) = "$" : C(4) = "04" : S(4) = "b ww b www bb ww"
        B(5) = "%" : C(5) = "05" : S(5) = "b www b ww bb ww"
        B(6) = "&" : C(6) = "06" : S(6) = "b ww bb ww b www"
        B(7) = "'" : C(7) = "07" : S(7) = "b ww bb www b ww"
        B(8) = "(" : C(8) = "08" : S(8) = "b www bb ww b ww"
        B(9) = ")" : C(9) = "09" : S(9) = "bb ww b ww b www"
        B(10) = "*" : C(10) = "10" : S(10) = "bb ww b www b ww"
        B(11) = "+" : C(11) = "11" : S(11) = "bb www b ww b ww"
        B(12) = "," : C(12) = "12" : S(12) = "b w bb ww bbb ww"
        B(13) = "-" : C(13) = "13" : S(13) = "b ww bb w bbb ww"
        B(14) = "." : C(14) = "14" : S(14) = "b ww bb ww bbb w"
        B(15) = "/" : C(15) = "15" : S(15) = "b w bbb ww bb ww"
        B(16) = "0" : C(16) = "16" : S(16) = "b ww bbb w bb ww"
        B(17) = "1" : C(17) = "17" : S(17) = "b ww bbb ww bb w"
        B(18) = "2" : C(18) = "18" : S(18) = "bb ww bbb ww b w"
        B(19) = "3" : C(19) = "19" : S(19) = "bb ww b w bbb ww"
        B(20) = "4" : C(20) = "20" : S(20) = "bb ww b ww bbb w"
        B(21) = "5" : C(21) = "21" : S(21) = "bb w bbb ww b ww"
        B(22) = "6" : C(22) = "22" : S(22) = "bb ww bbb w b ww"
        B(23) = "7" : C(23) = "23" : S(23) = "bbb w bb w bbb w"
        B(24) = "8" : C(24) = "24" : S(24) = "bbb w b ww bb ww"
        B(25) = "9" : C(25) = "25" : S(25) = "bbb ww b w bb ww"
        B(26) = ":" : C(26) = "26" : S(26) = "bbb ww b ww bb w"
        B(27) = ";" : C(27) = "27" : S(27) = "bbb w bb ww b ww"
        B(28) = "<" : C(28) = "28" : S(28) = "bbb ww bb w b ww"
        B(29) = "=" : C(29) = "29" : S(29) = "bbb ww bb ww b w"
        B(30) = ">" : C(30) = "30" : S(30) = "bb w bb w bb www"
        B(31) = "?" : C(31) = "31" : S(31) = "bb w bb www bb w"
        B(32) = "@" : C(32) = "32" : S(32) = "bb www bb w bb w"
        B(33) = "A" : C(33) = "33" : S(33) = "b w b www bb www"
        B(34) = "B" : C(34) = "34" : S(34) = "b www b w bb www"
        B(35) = "C" : C(35) = "35" : S(35) = "b www b www bb w"
        B(36) = "D" : C(36) = "36" : S(36) = "b w bb www b www"
        B(37) = "E" : C(37) = "37" : S(37) = "b www bb w b www"
        B(38) = "F" : C(38) = "38" : S(38) = "b www bb www b w"
        B(39) = "G" : C(39) = "39" : S(39) = "bb w b www b www"
        B(40) = "H" : C(40) = "40" : S(40) = "bb www b w b www"
        B(41) = "I" : C(41) = "41" : S(41) = "bb www b www b w"
        B(42) = "J" : C(42) = "42" : S(42) = "b w bb w bbb www"
        B(43) = "K" : C(43) = "43" : S(43) = "b w bb www bbb w"
        B(44) = "L" : C(44) = "44" : S(44) = "b www bb w bbb w"
        B(45) = "M" : C(45) = "45" : S(45) = "b w bbb w bb www"
        B(46) = "N" : C(46) = "46" : S(46) = "b w bbb www bb w"
        B(47) = "O" : C(47) = "47" : S(47) = "b www bbb w bb w"
        B(48) = "P" : C(48) = "48" : S(48) = "bbb w bbb w bb w"
        B(49) = "Q" : C(49) = "49" : S(49) = "bb w b www bbb w"
        B(50) = "R" : C(50) = "50" : S(50) = "bb www b w bbb w"
        B(51) = "S" : C(51) = "51" : S(51) = "bb w bbb w b www"
        B(52) = "T" : C(52) = "52" : S(52) = "bb w bbb www b w"
        B(53) = "U" : C(53) = "53" : S(53) = "bb w bbb w bbb w"
        B(54) = "V" : C(54) = "54" : S(54) = "bbb w b w bb www"
        B(55) = "W" : C(55) = "55" : S(55) = "bbb w b www bb w"
        B(56) = "X" : C(56) = "56" : S(56) = "bbb www b w bb w"
        B(57) = "Y" : C(57) = "57" : S(57) = "bbb w bb w b www"
        B(58) = "Z" : C(58) = "58" : S(58) = "bbb w bb www b w"
        B(59) = "[" : C(59) = "59" : S(59) = "bbb www bb w b w"
        B(60) = "\" : C(60) = "60" : S(60) = "bbb w bbbb w b w"
        B(61) = "]" : C(61) = "61" : S(61) = "bb ww b wwww b w"
        B(62) = "^" : C(62) = "62" : S(62) = "bbbb www b w b w"
        B(63) = "_" : C(63) = "63" : S(63) = "b w b ww bb wwww"
        B(64) = "`" : C(64) = "64" : S(64) = "b w b wwww bb ww"
        B(65) = "a" : C(65) = "65" : S(65) = "b ww b w bb wwww"
        B(66) = "b" : C(66) = "66" : S(66) = "b ww b wwww bb w"
        B(67) = "c" : C(67) = "67" : S(67) = "b wwww b w bb ww"
        B(68) = "d" : C(68) = "68" : S(68) = "b wwww b ww bb w"
        B(69) = "e" : C(69) = "69" : S(69) = "b w bb ww b wwww"
        B(70) = "f" : C(70) = "70" : S(70) = "b w bb wwww b ww"
        B(71) = "g" : C(71) = "71" : S(71) = "b ww bb w b wwww"
        B(72) = "h" : C(72) = "72" : S(72) = "b ww bb wwww b w"
        B(73) = "i" : C(73) = "73" : S(73) = "b wwww bb w b ww"
        B(74) = "j" : C(74) = "74" : S(74) = "b wwww bb ww b w"
        B(75) = "k" : C(75) = "75" : S(75) = "bb wwww b ww b w"
        B(76) = "l" : C(76) = "76" : S(76) = "bb ww b w b wwww"
        B(77) = "m" : C(77) = "77" : S(77) = "bbbb w bbb w b w"
        B(78) = "n" : C(78) = "78" : S(78) = "bb wwww b w b ww"
        B(79) = "o" : C(79) = "79" : S(79) = "b www bbbb w b w"
        B(80) = "p" : C(80) = "80" : S(80) = "b w b ww bbbb ww"
        B(81) = "q" : C(81) = "81" : S(81) = "b ww b w bbbb ww"
        B(82) = "r" : C(82) = "82" : S(82) = "b ww b ww bbbb w"
        B(83) = "s" : C(83) = "83" : S(83) = "b w bbbb ww b ww"
        B(84) = "t" : C(84) = "84" : S(84) = "b ww bbbb w b ww"
        B(85) = "u" : C(85) = "85" : S(85) = "b ww bbbb ww b w"
        B(86) = "v" : C(86) = "86" : S(86) = "bbbb w b ww b ww"
        B(87) = "w" : C(87) = "87" : S(87) = "bbbb ww b w b ww"
        B(88) = "x" : C(88) = "88" : S(88) = "bbbb ww b ww b w"
        B(89) = "y" : C(89) = "89" : S(89) = "bb w bb w bbbb w"
        B(90) = "z" : C(90) = "90" : S(90) = "bb w bbbb w bb w"
        B(91) = "{" : C(91) = "91" : S(91) = "bbbb w bb w bb w"
        B(92) = "|" : C(92) = "92" : S(92) = "b w b w bbbb www"
        B(93) = "}" : C(93) = "93" : S(93) = "b w b www bbbb w"
        B(94) = "~" : C(94) = "94" : S(94) = "b www b w bbbb w"

        'these code are not yet implemented
        B(95) = "del" : C(95) = "95" : S(95) = "b w bbbb w b www"
        B(96) = "func3" : C(96) = "96" : S(96) = "b w bbbb www b w"
        B(97) = "func2" : C(97) = "97" : S(97) = "bbbb w b w b www"
        B(98) = "Shift" : C(98) = "98" : S(98) = "bbbb w b www b w"
        B(99) = "Code C" : C(99) = "99" : S(99) = "b w bbb w bbbb w"
        B(100) = "func4" : C(100) = "Code B" : S(100) = "b w bbbb w bbb w"
        B(101) = "Code A" : C(101) = "Code A" : S(101) = "bbb w b w bbbb w"
        B(102) = "func1" : C(102) = "func1" : S(102) = "bbbb w b w bbb w"
        B(103) = "Start A" : C(103) = "Start A" : S(103) = "bb w b wwww b ww"

        'starting sign
        B(104) = "Start B" : C(104) = "Start B" : S(104) = "bb w b ww b wwww"

        'not implemented yet
        B(105) = "Start C" : C(105) = "Start C" : S(105) = "bb w b ww bbb ww"

        'very important...
        B(106) = "Stop" : C(106) = "Stop" : S(106) = "bb www bbb w b w bb"

        If foo = "" Then
            MsgBox("Error has occured!") ' no string ;-(
            Exit Function
        End If

        w(0) = "104" 'start
        check = 104 'start check value
        l = foo.Length
        For n = 1 To l
            For i = 0 To 94
                If foo.Substring(n - 1, 1) = B(i) Then
                    w(n) = C(i)
                    Exit For
                End If

            Next
            check = check + n * CInt(C(i))
            'MsgBox(CStr(n * CInt(C(i))))
        Next

        'MsgBox(CStr(check))

        l = l + 1
        w(l) = C(check Mod 103) 'checkzahl - check number

        l = l + 1
        w(l) = "106" 'stop

        Dim p As String = ""
        For n = 0 To l
            p = p + CStr(w(n)) & " "
        Next
        'MsgBox(p)

        For n = 0 To l
            Code128B2 = Code128B2 + S(CInt(w(n))) & " " 'ascii pendant basseln
        Next

        Code128B2 = Replace(Code128B2, " ", "")
        Return Code128B2

    End Function

       Private Sub btngenerate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btngenerate.Click
        textboxstring.Text = Code128B(textinput.Text)
        PictureBox1.Image = Code128Malen(textboxstring.Text)
    End Sub

    Private Sub print_dialog1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles print_dialog1.Click
        PrintDialog1 = New PrintDialog

        PrintDialog1.Document = PrintDocument1
        Dim r As DialogResult = PrintDialog1.ShowDialog
        If r = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            PrintDocument1.Print()

        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub PrintDocument1_PrintPage(sender As Object, e As PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.PrintPage
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(PictureBox2.Image, 0, 0)

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Is there definitely an image set on the `PictureBox` (or is it set to `BackgroundImage`)? If yes, maybe you need to set width/height as well.

Comment: basically the image is generated when I enter text into a textbox and it generates a barcode.

Comment: Are you generating an image in PictureBox2, or just drawing in PictureBox2?  We don't see your PictureBox2 code.

Comment: Furthermore, are you sure your _PrintPage event handler is called at all? If nothing works, you can try to use a Barcode font instead of a picture.

Comment: i have provided the entire code, hope it helps.